# How to save blob file to to asp.net server?

Tags: stream, blob, wav

i just created an application to save audio file using the 'recorder.js' (https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs). but i am unable to save the result audio file to server.

Please help he if you know.

i tried the follwong

*javascript*

```
  function upload(blobOrFile) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('POST', '/upload.aspx', true);
      xhr.onload = function (e) {
          var result = e.target.result;
          alert(result);
      };

      xhr.send(blobOrFile);
  }
```

and in upload.asspx page i used the following code in load event

Request.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/userfiles/" + "name" + ".wav"),true);

even it creates a wave file,its not working.

please help

Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

```
Request.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/userfiles/" + "name" + ".wav"),False);
```

Include Headers parameter should be set to false..